# How to convert literal string to normal string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

For example: `mystr="\"http:\\/\\/somedomain.com\"";`

i want to convert this string to `"http://somedomain.com";`

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` dont work

how can convert this?

Comment: Sample string represents ( "http:\/\/somedomain.com" )

Comment: ebattu, are the double escapes after http correct?

Answer (score 5):

This is because you need to escape the "\" and the quotes (") character in C#. There is no Encoding / Decoding to do. If you want to get rid of the confusing backslashes add a @ before your string

myStr = @"http://www.google.com"

Nevertheless, your string looks weird so you will need to get the text inside the quotes and then remove those weirdly placed "\"  in the http:// part.

Comment: this is dynamic string. not static

Comment: When i parsing json using `result=jsonValue.Parse(text).asDynamic(). After `result.domain` contains literal string. I need to convert `result.domain`

Comment: jike @jtimperley mentioned your encoding looks funky. There might be a way to get the value you need more easily. if not, you need to strip the quotes. Then just remove all "\" (considering it's a URI they shouldn't be there anyways...).

Comment: When i debugging `result.domain` error: cannot debug dynamic value. Next time `string mystr=result.domain.ToString();` Then watch `mystr` in debugger, looks like `"\"http:\\/\\/somedomain.com\""`

Comment: I am not that much in c# but this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/csharplanguage/thread/45eb90eb-bfb8-4c5e-a9a1-f76920dfdd6e) may help you. @ebattulga

Comment: You do __not__ have to escape `/` in C#.